# Canon 50mm f/1.8 lens won't go down to f/1.8

Tags: lens, canon, aperture, manual-mode, 50mm

Bought a 1.8 lens.

Today on manual I realised it won't go down to f/1.8, the lowest is f/2.8, but on other modes it does.

The camera is a Canon 5Ds.

p.s - just moved to canon so is there a setting I've missed?

Comment: What camera are you using it on? Are you trying to use it in bright light?

Comment: EOS 5DS and not bright light but I turned the light of aswell and won't scroll down to 1.8, but on auto with the light off it takes it at 1.8

Comment: To confirm, you are using manual exposure mode (and not manual something else, such as manual focus or manual AF point election)? What metering mode are you using?

Comment: Will the aperture respond to the rear control wheel to go up (to an aperture narrower than f/2.8)?

Answer (score 1):

Is the "Lock" switch near the bottom on the right side of the back of the camera slid to the right in the 'Lock' position?

[image: page 59 top]

If so, is the control you are trying to use to change the aperture selected under Custom Function **C.Fn3: Others → Multi function lock**?

[image: Page 410 bottom]

By default, the rear 'Quick Control Dial' on the back of the camera is locked by the Lock switch. Moving the 'Quick Control Dial' when it is locked will have no effect on the setting it is set to adjust. The 'Main Dial' (directly behind the shutter button) can also be selected to be locked, as can the eight-way 'Multicontroller' (often called the "joystick").

**Another possibility is that you have 'Safety Shift' enabled, along with using the camera's "slowest" allowed ISO and "fastest" (shortest) shutter duration. If 'Safety Shift' is enabled and there's too much light at the chosen (or lowest allowed) ISO and fastest allowed shutter speed, then the only thing the camera has left to "shift" is the aperture.**

For instance, if you are outdoors in bright light and the camera's fastest Tv is 1/8000 at ISO 100, that may still be too much light to allow a proper exposure at f/1.8. In fact, f/2.8 sounds about right in that scenario. 1/8000, f/2.8 at ISO 100 is EV 15, which is pretty much what direct sunlight with no clouds will give you.

Even if you are in dimmer light, if you have the ISO setting manually selected at a relatively high value, such as ISO 3200 or ISO 6400, and the shutter time at a relatively slow (longer) value, such as 1/60 second, then with 'Safety Shift' enabled and 'Av' selected within the 'Safety Shift' settings menu, the camera will stop down the aperture to prevent overexposure.

Please see pages 405-408 of your [EOS 5Ds / EOS 5Ds R Instruction Manual](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/9/0300018669/01/eos5ds-5dsr-im-en.pdf).